# Django inheritance and subclass attributes

Tags: python, django, inheritance, subclass

With a configuration such as this:

```
class A (models.Model):
    common_attribute = models.IntegerField()

class B (A):
    subclass_attribute = models.IntegerField()

class C (models.Model)
    a = ForeignKey(A)
```

... if an instance of C contains an instance of B, Django seems to treat this as an instance of A and I can't access c.a.subclass_attribute.  Is there a way around this?  I don't want to use abstract inheritance because of the difficulties with ForeignKeys - I want C to support any subclass of A.

Answer (score 1):

You can circumvent the difficulties with `ForeignKey` by using [django-polymorphic](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Django Polymorphic allows you to query the base class objects but retrieves the child class instances:

```
>>> Project.objects.create(topic="Department Party")
>>> ArtProject.objects.create(topic="Painting with Tim", artist="T. Turner")
>>> ResearchProject.objects.create(topic="Swallow Aerodynamics", supervisor="Dr. Winter")

>>> Project.objects.all()
[ <Project:         id 1, topic "Department Party">,
  <ArtProject:      id 2, topic "Painting with Tim", artist "T. Turner">,
  <ResearchProject: id 3, topic "Swallow Aerodynamics", supervisor "Dr. Winter"> ]
```

To use django polymorphic you only need to declare your models with Polymorphic Model as base class:

```
from django.db import models
from polymorphic import PolymorphicModel

class ModelA(PolymorphicModel):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class ModelB(ModelA):
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class ModelC(ModelB):
    field3 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Foreign keys will also return the child class instances, which I think is exactly what you want.

```
# The model holding the relation may be any kind of model, polymorphic or not
class RelatingModel(models.Model):
    many2many = models.ManyToManyField('ModelA')  # ManyToMany relation to a polymorphic model

>>> o=RelatingModel.objects.create()
>>> o.many2many.add(ModelA.objects.get(id=1))
>>> o.many2many.add(ModelB.objects.get(id=2))
>>> o.many2many.add(ModelC.objects.get(id=3))

>>> o.many2many.all()
[ <ModelA: id 1, field1 (CharField)>,
  <ModelB: id 2, field1 (CharField), field2 (CharField)>,
  <ModelC: id 3, field1 (CharField), field2 (CharField), field3 (CharField)> ]
```

Take into account that these queries will be [slightly less performant](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/performance.html).